# Black Screen after installing SageMath

Tags: boot, gui

This problem happened in my friend's computer, and I'm trying to help him out. He was using `Jupyter` for coding python, and installed SageMath using `sudo apt-get install sagemath`. He said that after that, the `Jupyter` kernel stopped working, so he decided to reboot his computer. The problem is, once he did this, he got a black screen, as shown below:
[image]

He said he can actually navigate the Ubuntu system, but there is no GUI. Here is another photo:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you type startx  to start the X server and desktop?

Answer (score 0):

The disk is full.  10% of a disk drive's space is reserved for root, which means that when a typical user program (like GNOME desktop) starts up and tries to create a log file, it can't.  Use the `du -hxd1 -t 10M` command repeatedly to track down what is eating up this space, and delete it.